# App crashes after setting CoreData Codegen to Category / Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, codegen

**Context**

My app uses `CoreData` and for the first version I was just using the `Class Definition` as the `Codegen Method` for all `Entities`. However, since I changed it to `Category / Extension`, the app crashes every time a `View` with a  `@FetchedResult` `Property Wrapper` is loaded.

> Crash Message: Thread 1: "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."

---

**Code**

```swift
// MyEntity.swift
public final class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Questions**

- What causes the crash and how can I resolve it?
- Is it necessary to define a new `CoreData` `Model Version` when only changing the `Codegen Method`?
- Is the change of the `Codegen Method` supported by `Lightweight Migration`?

Comment: When you changed the code gen style, did you create your own subclasses? If you’re using category/extension, you need to do that.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes I did that, you can see one example of a custom created subclass in the Code Section above. Could the problem be, that I named the file just `MyEntity.swift`, without the `+CoreDataClass`?

Comment: The name of the file doesn't matter. What I think you must have before the class name is `@objc(MyEntity)` since I believe Core Data uses that.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your reply. This solved the problem and using the CD Entities works fine now. What about the 2. and 3. question regarding the need of a new Model Version? Feel free to post your reply as an answer, so that I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: The answer to 2 is No since nothing has changed to the model itself. This means 3 is not relevant.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks a lot for your answers. Feel free to post it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your own subclass for a Core Data entity you must add the attribute @objc() to the declaration so that Core Data can find and use your subclass

```
@objc(MyEntity)
public final class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {
    // ...
}
```

As for changing the type of `codegen` it will not affect the Core Data model in anyway so there is nothing that needs to be migrated.